# How to sum and multiply values from TextViews in ListView and display them in a toast?

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview

I'm new at programming and it would be great if you could help me with this. I have an Activity which has a button and a listview. The values on the listview are name, price, category and quantity and are defined through an adapter. I would like to know how to multiply the quantity value of each row with the price value and sum all this values and show the result in a toast when the button is clicked. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/236cY.png) a graphic of it to understand it better.

Here's the code:

CartListActivity.java

```js
public class CartListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView userList;
    UserCustomAdapter userAdapter;
    ArrayList<User> userArray = new ArrayList<User>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart_list);

        Button payBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.payBtn);
        payBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total: x€", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
         });

        /**
         * add item in arraylist
         */
        userArray.add(new User("Olives verdes", "1,20€", "Aperitius", "0"));
        userArray.add(new User("Olives negres", "1,30€", "Aperitius", "0"));
        userArray.add(new User("Cogombrets", "1,80€", "Aperitius","0"));
        userArray.add(new User("Patates Lay's", "1,19€", "Aperitius","0"));
        userArray.add(new User("Potet", "0,95€", "Bebè","0"));
        userArray.add(new User("Biberó", "3,85€", "Bebè","0"));
        userArray.add(new User("Tovalloletes", "1,10€", "Bebè","0"));
        userArray.add(new User("Perxes de nadó", "1,95€", "Bebè","0"));
        /**
         * set item into adapter
         */
        userAdapter = new UserCustomAdapter(CartListActivity.this, R.layout.view_row,
                userArray);
        userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        userList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
        /**
         * get on item click listener
         */
        userList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    final int position, long id) {
                Log.i("List View Clicked", "**********");
                Toast.makeText(CartListActivity.this,
                        "List View Clicked:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

UserCustomAdapter.java

```js
public class UserCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<User> data = new ArrayList<User>();

    public UserCustomAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,
                             ArrayList<User> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        UserHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new UserHolder();
            holder.textName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.textPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.textCategory = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            holder.textQuantity = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.quantityTxt);
            holder.btnEdit = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            holder.btnDelete = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
        }
        final User user = data.get(position);
        holder.textName.setText(user.getName());
        holder.textPrice.setText(user.getPrice());
        holder.textCategory.setText(user.getCategory());
        holder.textQuantity.setText(user.getQuantity());
        final UserHolder finalHolder = holder;
        holder.btnEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String value1 = finalHolder.textQuantity.getText().toString();
                int a = Integer.parseInt(value1);

                if(a <= 99) {
                    int sum = a + 1;

                    Log.i("Edit Button Clicked", "**********");
                    user.setQuantity(Integer.toString(sum));
                    finalHolder.textQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
                }
            }
        });
        holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    String value2 = finalHolder.textQuantity.getText().toString();
                    int a = Integer.parseInt(value2);

                    if(a > 0) {
                        int substract = a - 1;
                        Log.i("Delete Button Clicked", "**********");
                        user.setQuantity(Integer.toString(substract));
                        finalHolder.textQuantity.setText(Integer.toString(substract));
                    }
            }
        });
        return row;

    }

    static class UserHolder {
        TextView textName;
        TextView textPrice;
        TextView textCategory;
        TextView textQuantity;
        Button btnEdit;
        Button btnDelete;
    }
}
```

User.java

```js
public class User {
    String name;
    String price;
    String category;
    String quantity;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(String price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public User(String name, String price, String category, String quantity) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.category = category;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

hoping that I've undestood your question, what if you loop through the userArray list inside the payBtn onClick method and get the total sum?
something like this:

```
Button payBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.payBtn);
    payBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int total = 0;
            for(User u: userArray){
                total += (u.getPrice()*u.getQuantity());
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total: +total+"€", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! In here I get errors in the '(u.getPrice()*u.getQuantity());' and in the 'Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total: +total+"€", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();' though

Comment: Can you tell what errors comes out? So I can help you

Answer (score 0):

so for your design, as I see in your code, you have an arrayList that holds all of your created items.
I would do something like this (create this function inside your activity class):

```
public class CartListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView userList;
UserCustomAdapter userAdapter;
ArrayList<User> userArray = new ArrayList<User>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart_list);

    Button payBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.payBtn);
    payBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total: x€", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     });

    /**
     * add item in arraylist
     */
    userArray.add(new User("Olives verdes", "1,20€", "Aperitius", "0"));
    userArray.add(new User("Olives negres", "1,30€", "Aperitius", "0"));
    userArray.add(new User("Cogombrets", "1,80€", "Aperitius","0"));
    userArray.add(new User("Patates Lay's", "1,19€", "Aperitius","0"));
    userArray.add(new User("Potet", "0,95€", "Bebè","0"));
    userArray.add(new User("Biberó", "3,85€", "Bebè","0"));
    userArray.add(new User("Tovalloletes", "1,10€", "Bebè","0"));
    userArray.add(new User("Perxes de nadó", "1,95€", "Bebè","0"));
    /**
     * set item into adapter
     */
    userAdapter = new UserCustomAdapter(CartListActivity.this, R.layout.view_row,
            userArray);
    userList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    userList.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    userList.setAdapter(userAdapter);
    /**
     * get on item click listener
     */
    userList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                final int position, long id) {
            Log.i("List View Clicked", "**********");
            Toast.makeText(CartListActivity.this,
                    "List View Clicked:" + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });

}
private double getTotalPrice(){
    double total = 0;
    if (userArray.size() == 0){ return total;}
    else {
        for (User user : userArray ) {
            double price = Double.parseDouble(user.getPrice()); // assuming you price is a string , and that you have getters and setters for all of the user's fields
            int quantity = Integer.parseInt(user.getQuantity());
            total = price*quantity;
        }
        return total;
    }
```

}

(if something is wrong in terms of syntax, I'll edit my answer)
and then in your onClick:

```
        payBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            double totalPrice = getTotalPrice();
            String msg = String.format("Total: %f€" , totalPrice ) // %f because the function returns double
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I haven't gotten any errors in the adapter but in the onClick it says cannot resolve method 'getTotalPrice()'

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you where you should paste the getTotalPrice function.

Comment: Now it says 'cannot resolve symbol data' in the getTotalPrice(). I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or I've missed something. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: switch 'data' with 'userArray' by data I meant the name of your arrayList , I'll edit my answer again.

Comment: No errors now but the app crashes when I touch the button. Could that be because maybe I haven't set getters or setters? I'm new and I don't know what these mean

Comment: getters and setters are function inside User class that used to get and set the fields of the user. for example: public double getPrice() { return this.price;} , but if you have no errors it's not the problem. everytime that app crashes it should print an error, try to run it through the debugger

Comment: This is what the debugger says when the app crashes, hope it helps https://pastebin.com/MpgxxWSk

Comment: Could you help me?

Comment: I think you should enhance your basic programing skills before you jump into this task... The error reads that you try to do numbers operations on string. You need to parse that string into decimal. Next time Google for the error, it's very basic one

Answer (score 0):

```
    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        long total=0;
        for(User u:userArray){
          String priceAsString=u.getPrice();
          String priceWithOutCamma=priceAsString.replaceAll(",","");
          String priceWithOutSign=priceWithOutCamma.replaceAll("€","");
          int price=Integer.valueOf("priceWithOutSign");
          int quantity=Integer.valueOf(u.getQuantity());
          total+=price*quantity;
       }
    DecimalFormat format=new DecimalFormat("#,###");
    String totalFormatted=format.format(total);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Total: " +totalFormatted+"€", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```